# Strawberry GraphQL Django limiting filtering options in GraphiQL interface

Tags: django, graphql, strawberry-graphql

So I have two graphql filters for a foreign key that works in Strawberry GraphQL Django v0.31.

```
@strawberry.django.filters.filter(models.Client, lookups=True)
class ClientFilter:
    id:auto
    name:auto

@strawberry.django.filters.filter(models.Matter, lookups=True)
class MatterFilter:
    id: auto
    client:'ClientFilter'
    category:auto
```

In the GraphiQL page they produce a filter that looks like this:

[image]

I don't need all the filter fields for the user because some of them don't make sense like using isNull or a regex field for an id. Is there a way to limit the filter options so it is less cluttered?

Comment: I don't think so... You can open a PR though.

Comment: @ccsv, opening an issue on strawberry django might be the best way to go fo this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but yes you can do that but you would have to define your own input like so:

```
@strawberry.input
class LimitedFilterLookup(Generic[T]):
    i_contains: Optional[T] = UNSET
```

And then instead of using auto for the fields of the filter you would declare them like this:

```
@strawberry.django.filters.filter(models.Client)
class ClientFilter:
    name: LimitedFilterLookup[str]
```